# Whats the best way to resolve requireJS conflicts in 3rd party modules

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I have 2 modules, Cart2Quote and a Swissup Ajax module. Both have requireJs configs that override the catalogAddToCart mapping.

Siwssup_Ajaxpro
[image: Siwssup_Ajaxpro]

Cart2Quote
[image: Cart2Quote]

So the Cart2Quote modules init function is never called.

I've searched but can't find any advice for resolving issues like this.

Comment: Well those are 2 unrealted changes from 2 unrelated vendors, so you need to merge it yourself into 1 file, and do the logic you need in correct order

Comment: @GosuPrzmak is there a way to stop the original 2 files from loading? Or Does my catalogAddToCart then become the final one loaded and override the originals?

Comment: Original 2 files ? Originally there is one file in magento, if you want to stop those 2 files from external vendors from loading then you can do this... in your new module, set dependencies to Cart2Quote & Swissup  (module.xml to make sure that your module is loaded after those 2 external vendors), after dependencies are set, create a requireJs file and add the original mapping which is used in Magento (browsing vendor files for catalogAddToCart should help you find it).
Look my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A follow up to your comment @Luke

Please review it if I didn't make any typos.

My/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="My_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Swissup_Ajaxpro"/>
            <module name="Cart2Quote_Quotation"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

My/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'My_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

My/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "catalogAddToCart": "Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart"
        }
    }
};
```

**Please keep one thing in mind**

Modules are loaded before design, so if any requirejs-config.js you mentioned is located in DESIGN folder, you will need to apply a requirejs-config.js change in design.

Answer (score 1):

This catalogAddToCart is a jquery widget, it should be overwritten using mixin, but they choose to replace the whole file, I think there is a reason.

You can contact either vendor to get support about this.